# Overloading Function templates Rules

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, function-templates

The following snippet is from the book C++ templates 2nd edition.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max (T1 a, T2 b)
{
return b < a ? a : b;
}
template<typename RT, typename T1, typename T2>
RT max (T1 a, T2 b)
{
return b < a ? a : b;
}

auto b = ::max<long double>(7.2, 4); // uses second template
```

My question is why ::max(7.2, 4) used the second template? Shouldn't both function templates match since long double can be the type of T1 or RT? Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: `7.2` is a `double`, not `long double`. So second template is a better match.

Comment: but for the 2nd template, the return value should also be `long double`, which requires also implicit conversion from `double` or `int` to long double, so that for both 1st or 2nd, there are implicit conversions?

Comment: Yes. But return value/type doesn't play a role in template deduction. Only the parameters passed to the function. When choosing which overload to use, the body of the function is never even looked at. Only the function signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 1st overload, if `T1` is specified as `long double`, and pass `7.2` which is a `double`, the implicit conversion from `double` to `long double` is required. For the 2nd overload, `RT` is specified as `long double`, and `T1` will be deduced as `double`, so it's an exact match and wins in overload resolution.

If you specify template argument as `double` as `::max<double>(7.2, 4);`, both of them are exact match and the call will be ambiguous.

Comment: there is a follow-up question.  For the 2nd overload, `T1` will be deduced as `double` and `T2` will be deduced as `int`. The return value should also be `double`, which requires also implicit conversion from `double` to `long double`?

Comment: @Willi Yes, implicit conversion is required when returns. But [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) doesn't consider return statement and return value. *In general, the candidate function whose parameters match the arguments most closely is the one that is called.*

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `T1` and `T2` can be made auto by the compiler as the argument you passed on `(7.2,4)` (`T1` now will be `double` and `T2` now will be `int` or `long`) but you also include another typename (and you don't have any other overload which accepts one typename) so the compiler thinks `long double` is the first argument of the second overload and auto the other twos.